# postMessage on React Native webview redirecting page in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-native, expo

I have an expo react native mobile app that uses a webview that access a page on my Rails server.  When I try to do window.postMessage from the server side, rails gives me an error that the route doesn't exist.  I haven't been able to find any documentation around this issue.  Any ideas what it happening here?

[image]

Comment: please add your `routes.rb` code

Comment: my routes have no reference to anything related to postMessage.  Should they?  This function is intended to communicate data back to the containing window.

Comment: it should have a way to reference it from an URL, another option is to add a JS function in the Rails side that handle all the logic of what you want to achieve, then you can call that function from the webview

Comment: Happening to me as well, the Webview is redirecting to a 404 page. How did you fix this?

Comment: I ended up taking a different approach.